# How to create a three way pivot using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

Very new to Laravel but am loving what I am seeing so far.

I am working on an application where Clients attend Sessions and Sessions can be attended by many Clients. In addition to this, Clients may also complete Assessments in Sessions they attend on an individual basis (i.e. one client = one assessment). Also worth pointing out that they may or may not complete an assessment.

Best way to explain this is...

[image]

It's also important to point out that the data must be consistent - a completed assessment must be done in a session where a client was present. i.e. the client must have been present at the session - the same is true of the inverse - a client can't have completed and assessment for a session he or she was not present at.

This is more of trying to wrap my head around the best structure for this and use the Eloquent ORM in Laravel. I know I can make a working solution to this which definitely will be garbled and messy, but I would rather know the correct way.

Some pertinent code:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
    }

    public function assessments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Assessment');
    }
}

class Session extends Model
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
    }

    public function assessments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Assessment');
    }
}

//This is where I am having difficulty...

class Assessment extends Model
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client');
    }

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Session');
    }
}
```

The issue I face is how to create this three way relationship between "Client", "Session" and "Assessment" in such a way that integrity is enforced and access is available.

Few things I have thought about:

1. Create a "client_session" pivot table and add an additional field to it called "assessment_id" and use this to bind an assessment to a unique combination of client and session. I'm not sure how (or even if it is possible) to define such a relationship to a table without a model.
2. Use "Assessments" as the pivot table. I don't really like this idea as it is possible that no assessments take place but I still need that relationship between client and session and storing that in "Assessments" feels wrong.
3. Create a separate table "Attendance" and an associated "pivot class" i.e. extends Pivot not Model - really unsure about this one!

I have managed to structure the data using simple tables and use INNER JOINs away from Laravel but wanted to understand how best to implement this with Eloquent.

I've also seen the belongsToMany() relationship using a Pivot (i.e. extends Pivot rather than Model) or the hasManyThrough() relationship.

I also saw https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot but this hasn't been maintained in 4 years so I assume this can be done with whatever ships with Eloquent/Laravel.

Any help, greatly appreciated!

**** UPDATE  ****

Okay, so @barghouthi has help massively with my understanding. Currently my models look like the following:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Session', 'attendance')->using('App\Attendance');
    }
}

class Session extends Model
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client', 'attendance')->using('App\Attendance');
    }
}

class Attendance extends Pivot
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'attendance');
    }

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Session', 'attendance');
    }

    public function assessment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Assessment','attendance');
    }
}

class Assessment extends Model
{
    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Attendance');
    }

    public function client()
    {
        // for now
        return $this->attendance()->client();
    }

    public function session()
    {
        // for now
        return $this->attendance()->session();
    }
}
```

I've purposefully renamed the pivot table so that reflects the Pivot Class.

I've put some dummy data into the attendance table such that:

[image]

When I query the client sessions for client ID 1 this returns four entries rather than two. Four is correct in terms of the attendance table but I would like to have only two records returned - i.e. the sessions.

**** UPDATE

Okay - so a lot of learning and I'm not quite there. This is my current solution:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Session', 'attendance')->using('App\Attendance')->distinct('session_id');
    }

    public function assessments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Assessment', '\App\Attendance', 'client_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Session extends Model
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client', 'attendance')->using('App\Attendance')->distinct('client_id');
    }

    public function assessments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Assessment', '\App\Attendance', 'session_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Assessment extends Model
{   
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Client', 'attendance', 'id', 'client_id')->using('\App\Attendance');
    }

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Session', 'attendance', 'id', 'session_id')->using('\App\Attendance');
    }
}
```

The attendance table simply has id, client_id and session_id. I figured there was no need for assessment_id as there is a one to one relationship (i.e. an assessment(s) may or not be carried out by a client at a particualr session)

```
class Attendance extends Pivot
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'attendance');
    }

    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Session', 'attendance');
    }

    public function assessments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Assessment','attendance');
    }
}
```

This seems to to do the trick apart for the most part. If I try and call

```
$assessment->client->id
```

I get the follwing:

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Which means my relationships in Assessment are not quite right if I want to read the properties of related elements.

When I use

```
$assessment->client
```

The output is

```
[{"id":1,"created_at":"2018-10-24 19:15:41","updated_at":"2018-10-24 19:15:41","date_of_birth":"26 Sep 1974","gender":1,"initial_contact_date":"2013-05-01","initial_session_offered_date":"2002-07-06","contact_from":1,"presentation":"Vitae qui et nesciunt iste autem numquam earum. Illo repudiandae deleniti vel nesciunt non iure. Sunt est nemo ut excepturi illum temporibus.","counsellor_id":1,"pivot":{"id":1,"client_id":1}}]
```

So I am guessing I am close.

Answer (score 1):

so if you have `client_session` or `attendance` table with `id`, `client_id`, `session_id` and you use this table as foreign key in assessments table.

The thing is the pivot table can be a model

see [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) : Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function sessions()
    {
        // using intermediate model
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Session')->using('App\Attendance');
    }
}

class Session extends Model
{
    public function clients()
    {
        // using intermediate model
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Session')->using('App\Attendance');
    }
}


class Attendance extends Pivot
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Session');
    }

    public function Assessments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Assessment');
    }

}



class Assessment extends Model
{
    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Attendance');
    }

    public function client()
    {
        // for now
        return $this->attendance()->client();
    }

    public function session()
    {
        // for now
        return $this->attendance()->client();
    }
}
```

so this way you can't have an assessment without an attendance and an
attendance can have many assessments.

Assessment would look like:

`id`, `attendance_id`: refers to client and sessions

Comment: This has definitely put me on the right track. Thank you. One (hopefully final!) thing I am struggling with is that a client may complete two assessments in a single session. The issue here is that when it comes to pulling the sessions, it provides two records - i.e. 

`Record #1: client_id:1 session_id:1 assessment_id:1
Record #2: client_id:1 session_id:1 assessment_id:2`

The data is sound. I just need a way to filter this so that it only pulls out distinct sessions rather than each "attendance" record.

Comment: Thats no problem at all, an assessment belongs to an attendance, but attendance may have several assessments. actually there is a mistake in my answer. Assessment is a normal model ( extends Model) I'll fix it now

Comment: I noticed the pivot issue which means some of it is going in! With regards to the issue in my last comment, is this because the relationship is returning the data from the "attendance" table rather than the end "assessment" table. The data is correct but I need this to pull in DISTINCT records (a la SQL) so that it just gives me the sessions - as opposed to a record for each unique combination.

Comment: if you put some examples it would be easier to understand!.

Comment: Why would you have two attendance instances for the same client and session?

Comment: Because a client can complete more than one assessment in a session.

Comment: so you would have assessments table like > `id`, `attendance_id`, `assessment_details`. you will just add another record here same attendance_id, that way you have two assessments by the same client in one session,